# modifying a bit of code to ffmpeg / concat different audio formats into 1 long WAV file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, concatenation, opus

I have this script that I don't fully understand.  It allows me to take a few different files  (M4A and WEBM) and join them together with FFMPEG and create a long WAV of all of the audio.

I need to change this to add a third format (OPUS)

basically I want it to take all OPUS, m4A and WEBM audio files in a directory and joint them as one long WAV.

can anyone help me here

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done


INP="ffmpeg -hide_banner"
FCT=-1
FIL="-filter_complex "
for f in /media/jnono/sata_500gb_dump/working_dir_for_yt_grinding/*.{webm,m4a}; do
  INP+=" -i ${f}"
  ((FCT+=1))
  FIL+="[${FCT}:a:0]"
done
((FCT+=1))
INP+=" ${FIL}concat=n=${FCT}:v=0:a=1[a] -map [a] waveoutput.wav"
echo $INP
$INP
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`for f in /media/jnono/sata_500gb_dump/working_dir_for_yt_grinding/*.{webm,m4a}; do`

to

`for f in /media/jnono/sata_500gb_dump/working_dir_for_yt_grinding/*.{webm,m4a,opus}; do`

Comment: I knew that part, I didn't understand the bottom portion- can you explain it better?

Comment: I added the opus extension to the list of files which will be iterated by the shell.